# Crash when using std::thread to execute lambda function using Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, stl

I have this function, try to ignore the types of parameters and variables. I'm absolutely sure that the objects are still there (they are created on the same thread before calling this function).

```
void ClientLoadUnloadStressTestcase::RunMasterForScenarioOverTimeWithAllConnections(ConnectionsController* Controller, MasterIPC &MasterIpc){

// Signal clients that we are set-up
MasterIpc.SignalAllClients();

ComputeEndTimeForScenarioOverTime();

std::atomic_bool mustContinue = true;

std::thread t{ [&]() {
    while (mustContinue)
        RunNewConnectionsSet(Controller, m_connectionNumber, m_dataSize);
} };

// Wait for time to be elapsed and clients to finish filtering.
MasterIpc.WaitForAllClients(TIME_TO_WAIT_FOR_TESTCASE_PROCESSES_TO_FINISH);

mustContinue = false;
t.join();

// Signal clients that connections are finished
MasterIpc.SignalAllClients();
}
```

Now, the problem is that once in a while, on some builds, the generated program will crash on the newly created thread, right here:

```
std::thread t{ [&]() {
while (mustContinue)
    RunNewConnectionsSet(Controller, m_connectionNumber, m_dataSize);
} };
```

This is the callstack when the crash happened (I stripped out the arguments and other unnecessary information):

```
vrfcore!VerifierStopMessageEx+0x6d0
vfbasics!AVrfpCheckFirstChanceException+0xa2
vfbasics!AVrfpVectoredExceptionHandler+0x1a
ntdll!RtlpCallVectoredHandlers+0xe6
ntdll!RtlDispatchException+0x63
ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatch+0x3a (TrapFrame @ 00000001`4617f9e8)
0x00000001`43a25f50
dci_tester!std::_Invoker_functor::_Call+0x6
dci_tester!std::invoke+0x6 (Inline Function @ 00007ff6`2fa1b6cf)
dci_tester!std::_LaunchPad<std::unique_ptr<std::tuple<void (__cdecl*)(void *),void *>,std::default_delete<std::tuple<void (__cdecl*)(void *),void *> > > >::_Execute+0x6 
dci_tester!std::_LaunchPad<std::unique_ptr<std::tuple<void (__cdecl*)(void * __ptr64),void * __ptr64>,std::default_delete<std::tuple<void (__cdecl*)(void * __ptr64),void * __ptr64> > > >::_Run+0x6f 
dci_tester!std::_LaunchPad<std::unique_ptr<std::tuple<void (__cdecl*)(void *),void *>,std::default_delete<std::tuple<void (__cdecl*)(void *),void *> > > >::_Go+0x5 
dci_tester!std::_Pad::_Call_func+0x9
dci_tester!invoke_thread_procedure+0xe (Inline Function @ 00007ff6`2fbcd91d)
dci_tester!thread_start<unsigned int (__cdecl*)(void * __ptr64)>+0x5d
vfbasics!AVrfpStandardThreadFunction+0x4d
KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x22
ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x34
```

That address that you see on the stack `0x00000001'43a25f50` is actually the address of the `MyObject (this)` that is passed to the lambda function (because it is using it to run `MyObject::RunNewConnectionsSet` method).

This crash happens only on some builds, but the executable will always crash on that line. We had the issue from thread several times before, but now I really wanna find an answer. Please help :).

Visual Studio 2015 version `14.0.24720.41`

**UPDATE (added the main thread call-stack)**

```
ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0x14
KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0x9f
dci_tester!cppdex::WindowsSyncEvent::WaitForSignal+0x2e 
dci_tester!cppdex::testing::IpcDispatcher::WaitForSignalFromProcess+0x25 
dci_tester!MasterIPC::WaitForAllClients+0x4d 
dci_tester!dci_tester::testcases::ClientLoadUnloadStressTestcase::RunMasterForScenarioOverTimeWithAllConnections+0xa2 
dci_tester!dci_tester::testcases::ClientLoadUnloadStressTestcase::ConnectionsMasterProcessRoutine+0x1d1 
dci_tester!dci_tester::testcases::DciMultiProcessTestcase::ProcessRoutine+0x1c1 
dci_tester!cppdex::testing::MultiProcessTestcase::Run+0x6b
dci_tester!cppdex::testing::TestcaseManager<cppdex::testing::TestcaseDefaultCommandParser>::RunTestcase+0x175
dci_tester!ExecutableMain+0x64a
dci_tester!wmain+0x68
dci_tester!invoke_main+0x22
dci_tester!__scrt_common_main_seh+0x11d
kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x14
ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x21
```

Comment: Your code has undefined behavior.  You need to provide synchronization for `mustContinue`

Comment: @NathanOliver where does it say that it is undefined behavior ? can you give me the link in the standard? Or can you elaborate a bit? I don't understand how it can go so wrong cause in the end it's just a `mov` and a `cmp` or something like that.

Comment: @AlexandruBrinduse [According to the standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/intro.races#20) it is a data race and that is undefined behavior.

Comment: Writing to and reading from an unsynchronized variable from different threads is undefined behavior, period. If you think you're smarter than the compiler ("it's just a `mov` and `cmp`") you will hurt yourself badly. I recommend reading ["There are no benign data races"](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2013/01/06/benign-data-races-what-could-possibly-go-wrong). Now, this `mustContinue` thing is probably not the reason for your crash (and you can just make it a `std::atomic<bool>` to fix it), but blatant disregard for synchronization in general might be.

Comment: @MaxLanghof I never thought that the compiler can go so badly wrong because I write to a variable that is read by another thread without adding a "lock" there. I can understand the fact that one thread can read `false` even after the `true` assignment, but the program crashes 100%.

Comment: We will need a [mcve] to have any hope of understanding the problem.

Comment: @MaxLanghof As you assumed, the atomic_bool doesn't fix the crash. I understand that it was UB, now it isn't anymore and it's still 100% reproductible.

Comment: @PasserBy I have .exe / .pdb / .dmp whatever you like.. But it's in the same spot each and every time.. One thread is blocked in a WaitForSingleObject and the other thread crashes with the stack provided.